# Firestore: how to perform a query with inequality / not equals

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want select from Firestore collection just articles written NOT by me.

Is it really so hard?

> Every article has field "owner_uid".

Thats it: 
I JUST want to write equivalent to `"select * from articles where uid<>request.auth.uid"`

**TL;DR: solution found already:** usages for languages/platforms: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#kotlin+ktx_5

Comment: Firestore now supports "where in" operator. Check my answer and update accepted answer

Answer (score 95):

**EDIT Sep 18 2020**

The Firebase [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7210_-_september_17_2020) suggest there are now `not-in` and `!=` queries.  ([Proper documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_) is now available.)

- `not-in` finds documents where a specified field’s value is not in a specified array.
- `!=` finds documents where a specified field's value does not equal the specified value.

Neither query operator will match documents where the specified field is not present.  Be sure the see the documentation for the syntax for your language.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Firestore doesn't provide inequality checks.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries):

> The where() method takes three parameters: a field to filter on, a comparison operation, and a value. The comparison can be <, <=, ==, >, or >=.

Inequality operations don't scale like other operations that use an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).  Firestore indexes are good for range queries.  With this type of index, for an inequality query, the backend would still have to scan every document in the collection in order to come up with results, and that's extremely bad for performance when the number of documents grows large.

If you need to filter your results to remove particular items, you can still do that locally.

You also have the option of using multiple queries to exclude a distinct value.  Something like this, if you want everything except 12.  Query for value < 12, then query for value > 12, then merge the results in the client.

Comment: locally but how?
If collection "articles" has 10 thousands articles readed by me it means I have to query this collection with pagination crazy amount of times before i will reach UNreaded articles.

Comment: <br>for example, how to get only articles i DONT read already?<br>
storing readed_article_ids in my user Firestore Document will enlarge my user document and every firestore doc has limit in 1mb - some day readed_article_ids Firestore Array within my user document will exceed this threshold.<br>
So confused :(((

Comment: If you have a more specific question about data modeling, that sounds like a different question.

Comment: hm, do I need to create new question to get answer? ))
allright, I will right now, cuz' I read all the docs about data modeling and still have questions about it

Comment: Such annoying lacking of basic functionality makes me regret that I've picked Google Firebase as BaaS

Comment: There's no minefields here. Like any nosql database, you have to learn how to model your data in a way that suits your anticipated queries.

Comment: So I've made an app for creating articles. I've been surprised, when I haven't found any solution of how to show a list of articles created by other users. local filtering is bullshit in million(just one!) articles case. ^(

Comment: I edited the answer to include an option that may not be immediately obvious - using queries to exclude a single value from a range.

Comment: And what about if it's not a number but an id (alphanumeric)? This is quite annoying.

Comment: @b-fg You can use the same strategy.

Comment: Range queries for alphanumeric values? Please show me an example.

Comment: @b-fg It's just like numbers, except you use strings.  There is nothing special going on here - it's standard lexigographic comparison of strings.

Comment: @DougStevenson String comparison doesn't work for me. I get an empty response when I use two where clauses with ">" and "<".

Comment: For new comers, this answer is now out of date. Check my answer below for up to date answer .

Comment: @TSR this answer is not out of date.  What you're recommending in your answer isn't an inequality filter that gives everything but a specific value, as the OP requests.  It's implementing a query for a set of specific values.

Comment: Can you explain that further @DougStevenson I tried to implement != query, but weirdly it's JUST returning elements that logically are == to the requested attribute/value

Comment: @DavidSeek If you have a specific query that's not working the way you expect, please post a new question that illustrates the issue and that anyone can reproduce.

Comment: @DougStevenson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64001492/how-to-use-firebases-new-firestore-inequality-require-feature

Comment: Never-mind. I'm an idiot. Been getting from the wrong Node. Been storing the status update to the proper Node. That's why I was getting the same element over and over again. Well. That's a day I'm not getting back...

Comment: Now inequality filter `!=` is available in firebase sdk but seems not to work.

Comment: @Midou If you have a question, post it separately along with the code that isn't working the way you expect, and a description of what it's supposed to do instead.

Comment: @DougStevenson Do you know if/when the official docs are expected to be updated to include these new filters? The [WereFilterOp Ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore#wherefilterop) doesn't mention them. Also, the [Queries Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) still says `!=` is not supported. I'm specifically interested in knowing more about the indexing and security implications related to these new filters. Seems like and awfully big feature to drop and then only leave a couple hints in the release notes!

Comment: @CDoe I suggest reaching out to Firebase support if you have a question that can only be addressed by the Firebase team. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: edit your answer, it is real, NE queries are alive
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/09/cloud-firestore-not-equal-queries.html

Answer (score 6):

**For android it should be easy implement with [Task Api](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks). 
Newbie example:**

```
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Query lessQuery = db.collection("users").whereLessThan("uid", currentUid);
    Query greaterQuery = db.collection("users").whereGreaterThan("uid", currentUid);
    Task lessQuery Task = firstQuery.get();
    Task greaterQuery = secondQuery.get();

    Task combinedTask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(lessQuery , greaterQuery)
                             .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {

            //This is the list of "users" collection without user with currentUid
        }
    });
```

***Also, with this you can combine any set of queries.***

**For web there is [rxfire](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/rxfire)**

Comment: is this best practice? What are other solutions if i am using firestore paging adapter from firebase-ui

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of how I solved the problem in JavaScript:

```
let articlesToDisplay = await db
  .collection('articles')
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    let notMyArticles = snapshot.docs.filter( (article) => 
      article.data().owner_uid !== request.auth.uid
    )
    return notMyArticles
  })
```

It fetches all documents and uses Array.prototype.filter() to filter out the ones you don't want. This can be run server-side or client-side.

Comment: Did you count reads from your db in Firebase console?
I think in this way you always read all the 'atricles' db graph, and only then you filter items - which is too expensive by your server memory+cpu usage in the case of huge graph size

Comment: Yes, as stated this solution reads all documents from the collection. Inappropriate for large collections. You could filter on date to get articles from, say, the last week only to reduce the size, but depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer of **Darren G**, which caused "**TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**". When we perform the filter operation, the whole firebase object was added back to the **array** instead of **just the data**. We can solve this by **chaining** the **filter method** with the **map method.**

```js
let articles = []
let articlesRefs = await db.collection('articles').get();

articles = articlesRefs.docs
           .filter((article) => article.data.uid !== request.auth.uid) //Get Filtered Docs
           .map((article) => article.data()); //Process Docs to Data

return articles
```

FYI: This is an **expensive operation** because you will fetching all the articles from database and then filtering them locallly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Track all user id in a single document (or two)
2. filter unwanted id out
3. Use "where in"

```
var mylistofidwherenotme =  // code to fetch the single document where you tracked all user id, then filter yourself out


database.collection("articles").where("blogId", "in", mylistofidwherenotme)
```

Comment: you can't filter unwanted id's out from the document
and you also can't fetch every time all the ids to perform filtering locally - we speak about huge database

Answer (score -1):

```
let query = docRef.where('role','>',user_role).where('role','<',user_role).get()
```

This is not functioning as the "not equal" operation in firestore with string values

Comment: I don't think chaining .where would operate like OR logic, it should be AND logic. So this probably won't work?

Comment: You have to query separately for both conditions and join results, thus increasing the number of reads operation and sucking money out of your pocket

Comment: will return an empty list

Answer (score -1):

You can filter the array of objects within the javascript code.

```
var data=[Object,Object,Object] // this is your object array
var newArray = data.filter(function(el) {
   return el.gender != 'Male';
});
```