# Cloud Firestore - query all data except some data

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

A question about filtering data in a list.

My firestore database structure looks like:

```
drivers
    12345
        name: "Rob"
        age: 25
    67890
        name: "Bob"
        age: 22
    45678
        name: "Carl"
        age: 27

cars
    11111
        name: "Honda"
        driver: 12345
    22222
        name: "Mercedes"
        driver: 67890
    33333
        name: "Ford" 
        driver: 45678
```

I'm a driver too, the driver with the 45678 profile.
How can I list all other drivers, except me?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you included the collection cars? And what language are you using?

Comment: Firestore does not support inequality condition. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals

Comment: If you only want to list `drivers`, the `cars` list are not necessary in you question. If you want `inequality condition query`, Frank van Puffelen's answer will be correct answer.