# Cloud Firestore query result set is empty

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run the below query on the sample data provided in [firebase docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries):

```
cities.whereLessThan("population", 9000000)
        .whereGreaterThan("population", 9000000)
        .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
            Logger.log_error(TAG + " Task successful Result is Empty = " + task.getResult().isEmpty());
        }else {
            Logger.log_error(TAG + " Task failed = " + task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

I am expecting to get cities where the population is less than 9000000 and greater than 9000000. Eventually what I am trying to achieve is:
select * from TABLE where population <> 9000000 by combining whereLessThan and whereGreaterThan in the FireStore query.

Can someone please let me know if it isn't supported at all or am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore query conditions are **AND**ed together. So what you're asking for is: give me a cities with **more** than 9 million **and** with **less** than 9 million people. That's an empty set: no city can have both more **and** less than 9 million.

Comment: So stupid of me! I have gone thru the documentation 10 times but still missed the same. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: But is there a way to achieve what I intend to?

Comment: There is no built-in support for "not equal" operations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already I believe you have to create a [Cloud Firestore index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing)

in short:

> Cloud Firestore requires an index for every query, to ensure the best
>   performance. All document fields are automatically indexed, so queries
>   that only use equality clauses don't need additional indexes. If you
>   attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map to an
>   existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes a
>   direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.