# Firestore query filter retrieve document where field is missing

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello Firestore lovers !

I am trying to retrieve all documents that do not have a field set. Here my field is named "source".

- I can get the documents where "source" is equal "".
- I can also get the documents where "source" is null.
- But I can't find the way to get documents where source is not set at all in the document.

Sample python 3 working code using the google cloud python library :

```
from google.cloud import firestore

product_ref = "product"
db = firestore.Client()
doc_ref = db.collection(product_ref)

docs = doc_ref.where(u'source', u'==', None).get()
```

This works and returns all the document with source == null.

I have found very few lines on github on a IS_NAN operator but I have not been able to use it to get the documents where "source" field is missing.

Thank you !

Comment: There is no operator to check for inequality on the back-end: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals. The closest you can get is checking for non-existence of the field: https://twitter.com/abeisgreat/status/929808518428762112

Comment: Thank you for the link.
It was an "==" so I had hope it work.

The trick from @abeisgreat on Twitter is great but I am not sure it will save me on this. I will have to loop over all documents once.

Thanks again =)

Comment: The link to the twitter post is gone. Is there anywhere else I can find that? It is exactly what I need (check for non-existence of a field).