# How to use not/ inequality operator in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have list of strings, and using not operator I wanted to select all values except one. But I couldn't find anything about not opertor in the firebase website. Please help me with this issue.

P.S: This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals) explains how to do the inequality operation with numbers, and not strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a limitation with Cloud Firestore queries. But I found a workaround.
Cloud Firestore [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) states,

> "Queries with a != clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported, you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause where("age", ">", 30)."

Answer (score 0):

[New update](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/09/cloud-firestore-not-equal-queries.html) on Firestore now supports not equal and not in queries. [As mentioned](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_) here:

```
const capitalNotFalseRes = await citiesRef.where('capital', '!=', false).get();
const notUsaOrJapan = await citiesRef.where('country', 'not-in', ['USA', 'Japan']).get();
```