# Query firestore by inequality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I know this might be a duplicate of [Firestore: how to perform a query with inequality / not equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals) but I really did not get an answer I want from that question.

Firestore doesn't accept the inequality operator `!=`.

Suppose I want to query tasks that are not mine by uid. 
Querying for the tasks I created is easy since I only need to use `==`.

I have the following code.

```
export default function fetchTasks () {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const tasks = await db.collection('tasks')
      .where('owner', '>', `/users/${uid}`)
      .where('owner', '<', `/users/${uid}`)
      .get()

    const taskList = []
    tasks.forEach((task) => {
      taskList.push(task.data())
    })

    dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_TASKS_FULFILLED',
      payload: taskList
    })
  }
}
```

I can't seem to get this work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Sep 2020:** [v7.21.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore) introduced support for not equals (`!=`) queries!
That means you can simply do:

```js
const tasks = await db.collection('tasks')
      .where('owner', '!=', `/users/${uid}`)
      .get();
```

---

#### Original Answer

The answer from Doug to that questions says that you'll need to use two separate queries to get the results: one for `` db.collection('tasks').where('owner', '>', `/users/${uid}`) ``
and one for `` db.collection('tasks').where('owner', '<', `/users/${uid}`) ``. You'll then need to merge the results in your client-side code.

So:

```
const tasks = await db.collection('tasks')
  .where('owner', '<', `/users/${uid}`)
  .get()

let taskList = []
tasks.forEach((task) => {
  taskList.push(task.data())
})

tasks = await db.collection('tasks')
  .where('owner', '>', `/users/${uid}`)
  .get()
tasks.forEach((task) => {
  taskList.push(task.data())
})

dispatch({
  type: 'FETCH_TASKS_FULFILLED',
  payload: taskList
})
```

Comment: thank you. that worked! i thought a compound query would do it, but to no avail. one minor thing though is that you forgot to replace `const` with `let` but other than that, everything works great!

Comment: How to make sure we use limit filter while doing this? My collection has lot of documents and doing this way may bloat it up.