# Angular Firestore | how to get array not contain

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using Angular Firestore in my app, and I'm having a problem to write a query that will return all of the objects I'm needed

In the following example, I get all the fruits that got that user id in their eat_by array

```
this.asf.collection('fruits', ref => ref.where('eat_by', 'array-contains', userId)).valueChanges();
```

and its working great

But the problem I'm having is doing the opposite thing; I'm trying to get the fruits that don't have that userId in there eat by the array. 
Like `$nin` in mongo.

I need that the field value is not in the specified array operator

did you handle with that thing before ?

how did you resolve it ?

there is any good workaround ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There is no "array does not contain" operation is Cloud Firestore at the moment.

I highly recommend reading [Doug's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals), as it explains why this operation is not supported. Unfortunately the workaround proposed there, won't work for "array does not contain" operations.