# How can I get only the users with roles of 'user'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase for this app. Under each documents of a user, I have this array `roles`. For normal users, their `roles` would just be `user`. For an admin, it would be `user` and `admin`. I want to retrieve all of the normal users. However, the problem is that if I'll set it like this:

```
.collection("users")
.where("roles", "!=", "admin")
```

this will still show the user with an `admin` role.

[image]

How can I retrieve only those normal users and not the user with an `admin` role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require an `array-does-not-contain` operation, which does not exist in Firestore.

You might want to consider storing the roles as a map with boolean values, so that you can query for `where("roles.admin", "==", false)`.

Also see:

- [Firestore - Possible to query by array-not-contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59595938/firestore-possible-to-query-by-array-not-contains)
- [FireStore - how to get around array "does-not-contain" queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812558/firestore-how-to-get-around-array-does-not-contain-queries)
- [Angular Firestore | how to get array not contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572597/angular-firestore-how-to-get-array-not-contain)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'not-in'` roles not in admin then you will get normal user

docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Still the same. It still shows the user with the role of an admin