# Firebase operator 'not-in' is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this document on the database:
[image]

I want to query the amount of messages documents where the ID of the user is not in the array of "read_by". I have the following code:

```
const q = query(messagesRef, where('read_by', 'not-in', [user.uid]))
const docs = await getDocs(q)
```

But this where is not working.. It still returns the 2 documents, even tho both of them have the ID of the user inside the array. The "user.uid" is correct, returns the correct id of the user.

Answer (score 0):

The `not-in` operator includes a document in its results when a single-value field does not match of the values specified in an array. It does **not** handle array fields.

What you are looking for would be an `array-does-not-contain` operator, which Firestore does not support.

Also see:

- [FireStore - how to get around array "does-not-contain" queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812558/firestore-how-to-get-around-array-does-not-contain-queries)
- [Firestore get documents where value not in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085868/firestore-get-documents-where-value-not-in-array)
- [Structuring a firestore database to filter by what is not in the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903491/structuring-a-firestore-database-to-filter-by-what-is-not-in-the-array)
- [Angular Firestore | how to get array not contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572597/angular-firestore-how-to-get-array-not-contain/52573427#52573427)

Comment: Hmm.. And is there a workaround I can make?

Comment: No great one, as the database simply can't return items that are not its index. Check the links I included for the only option, which takes adding a map field with a default (`false`) values for all values. That's not often feasible though, hence: not a great one.

Comment: Well, what should I do then? Stop using firebase because I can't query for documents that does not contain a value on an array?