# Ignoring DocID in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple Query which is there to recommend Users under a Post related Posts.

```
await this.$fireStore.collection('posts')
.limit(6).where('tags', 'array-contains', this.post.tags[0]).get().then(querySnapshot => {
```

Problem is that this also Reads out the Post itself (since it contains the Tag too), is there any way to query for Posts that dont have a specific DocID without wasting a Where ergo needing a complete new Query?

Comment: If I understands correctly that you would like to only read (fetch) a part of a document, this is not possible: with a query you will get the entire document. You may duplicate your data if, for example, the volume of one document is too important to be downloaded when you only need a small subset of its data.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec No this is completly not what I want, I wanna get documents except a document with a specific ID

Comment: Ok, I understand! I've proposed an approach in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't provide the possibility to query with inequality (i.e. not equals), see for example this SO post: [Firestore: how to perform a query with inequality / not equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals)

I understand that you want to get a maximum of 6 "sibling" posts. You could make the same query, with a limit of 7 docs and, **in your front-end**, filter the result:

By looping over the list of docs and compare their Id to the current doc Id you will encounter two cases:

1. The current doc is within the 7 docs returned by the query: remove it from the list
2. The current doc is NOT within the 7 docs returned by the query: remove one doc randomly.