# Is it possible to exclude several specific documents from cloud firestore query?

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am building an Android(java) app that reads data from cloud firestore and displays said data in a list view. Currently I am planing on querying using GeoHash as a means to sort data.
Since there is a lot of data to be retrieved from firebase I am looking for a way to reduce the amount of reads per average user (to reduce potential cost).

My idea is to store entire documents locally and ignore those documents from future queries for a limited period of time(a week or so). I am aware that there is no != ekvivalent in cloud firestore but i was wandering if there is a possibility to skip documents using their ids or something similar.

If there is no such a thing I was wondering what is the best way to accomplish 
similar effect. (using the classic >=5 and <= 7 approach to ignore 6 would be impossible since I need to hide several documents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore does not support [exclusions from queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals). The only way to create an exclusion is by combining multiple range operations as you've already found. If that doesn't allow you to implement your use-case, Firestore may not be the best fit for it.

Comment: Thanks for quick response :)