# How do I 'filter in' firestore data satisfying 'where not equal to' condition?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter data in firestore and display it in my application. I can see ***"where Equal To"*** condition in firestore api but I need ***"where not Equal to"***.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Comment: in firestore -- >

db.collection("allOrders").whereEqualTo("offersProviderId", id )
But I want all orders that do not contain the Id

Comment: No. From what you already tried.

Comment: If you can be more specific as to what you are querying for and perhaps and example of your Firestore structure and the code you've attempted, we may be able to present a solution. Otherwise, the question is too vague.

Comment: Firestore does not currently support inequality queries. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals

Answer (score 2):

You can see from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) that `Where` queries do not have a `not equal to` operator, so this is not possible

> The where() method takes three parameters: a field to filter on, a comparison operation, and a value. The comparison can be <, <=, ==, >, >=, or array-contains. For iOS, Android, and Java, the comparison operator is explicitly named in the method.

I would suggest trying to structure your data in a way that there is an alternate field that stores some sort of boolean value for use in your query. Alternatively you could just get the full collection and filter out after. Assuming we are talking about a single doc this shouldn't be much more expensive as an operation

Comment: Actually, it is possible. You can use < and > operators to get everything 'around' the item you don't want. So for example; suppose you store the alphabet A, B, C, D, E etc and you want all the letters that are NOT 'N'. This is done by querying all letters less than N and all letters that are greater than N. A real solution though would depend on what the structure is and what is being queried.

Comment: valid point, although I'd be surprised if this worked out to be very efficient - but again as you say that would depend entirely on the structure being queried.

Comment: @Jay - Since Firestore doesn't support `or` in queries, that would be 2 separate queries that you need to merge clientside.

Comment: @AjahnCharles Correct, as the links suggest.

Comment: is there a data structure that would remove the need of the not equal query but provide the same functionality?

My current structure is as follows, a "jobs" collection where each document has a field called "createdBy" that contains the uid of the user who created that document, how can i list all the job documents that aren't created by my currently logged in user without combining queries? what changes could i make to my data structure?

Comment: As I'm guessing there are a lot more jobs that aren't than that are and sounds like every user can access the full list, so I'd say just query the full list of jobs and filter out client-side. I don't think you'd save much with complex queries in this case.