# Get records other than a string value with angularfirestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I need to build a query where the field value is different from a string value.

I looked in the documentation and couldn't understand how to make a query where the value is different.

With `angularfirestore` I can't make an appointment as follows:

```
    this.db.collection('schedules').doc(id)
        .collection('values', ref => 
        ref.where('status', '!==', 'cancel');
```

**I need to get all records whose status is different from cancel.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore: how to perform a query with inequality / not equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals)

Answer (score 0):

look a documentation in oficial library; https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

Basically you have to follow this example:

```
db.collection ('items', ref => ref.where ('size', '==', 'large'))
```