# Need help resolving firebase query

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My node backend is connected to Firestore. I need to perform this MySQL equivalent query:

```
SELECT * FROM offer WHERE zip = '..' AND category = '...' AND status != 1 ORDER BY ..
```

So far I tried below Firebase query:

```
const docRef = db.collection('ads');
await docRef.where('status', '<', 4).where('status', '>', 5).orderBy('status')
.where('zip', '==', searchTerm).where('subCategory', '==', subCategory).orderBy('createdAt')
```

This query returns empty array. I'm fairly new to Firebase.

Comment: Your query is checking for status less than 4 and greater than 5. Based on your MySQL query I think you want `where('status', '!=', 1)`

Comment: @jmalenfant Firebase does not have an inequality (`'<>'` or `'!='`) [operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators) that can be used in `where(...)`.

Comment: @samthecodingman Odd. He could just use `.query()` and use SQL then, correct?

Comment: To keep Firestore queries performant, they just aren't supported. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47252340).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) (from `db.collection(...)`) should be named `colRef` or similar. While similar to a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference), they work differently and mean different things.

Your query defined by this line, says "find documents where status must be less than 4 AND greater than 5 AND sort them by their value of status".

```
colRef.where('status', '<', 4).where('status', '>', 5).orderBy('status')
```

Because the value of `status` cannot be both larger than 5 and smaller than 4, you get no results.

If you wanted to translate your SQL query, you would use:

```
colRef.where('status', '>', 1).orderBy('status')
.where('zip', '==', searchTerm).where('subCategory', '==', subCategory).orderBy('createdAt');
```

This assumes that status is never less than 1. If it is, you will also need a second, separate query:

```
colRef.where('status', '<', 1).orderBy('status')
.where('zip', '==', searchTerm).where('subCategory', '==', subCategory).orderBy('createdAt')
```