# How to get documents from Firestore without a single document id

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So i have a collection named products in my Firestore and it contains all my products.
Since i am using Tag widget it gives me an error when there is more than one item sharing the same tag. So for my Products Builder i want to give a list that contains all my products without a specific product catched by his id, so stream property of my Stream Builder can be like this.

```
StreamBuilder(stream: Firestore.instance.collection('products').WITHOUT SPECIFIC PRODUCT ID .snapshot()
builder:...)
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Do some research before asking here on SO. There is a [`snapshots`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) method that you can use.

Comment: Are you saying you just want to query the products collections for all documents?

Comment: all documents less the one. Something like where method but instead of isEqaulTo, inNotEqualTo

Comment: I've done all the research Chris but still i didn't get it

Comment: What do you mean by "all documents less the one."?

Comment: Hi, I suggest you take a look at this document https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to construct a query for all documents except one.  [There are no inequality filters in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals).

Since it's just one document, it makes sense to simply do the query for all documents, the have the client code remove the one you don't want from the result set.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it' s still not possible even if i want to do this with category? Like  Firestore.instance.collection('products').where(Category, ISNOTEQUALTO : 'Shoes').snapshots(); so i'll get all documents exept ones that have Shoes as their Category name.

Comment: last thing, is it possible to shuffle them like with lists? I' ve searched for a method shuffle but it haven't

Comment: As I said in my answer, there are no inequality filters in Firestore.  If you have additional questions, please post them separately.

Comment: If Doug answer your question you could follow the recommendations on this document https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers