# Node.js runtime on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently trying to find a backend solution for my mobile app. I ran into issues in the past with the limited querying power of Cloud Firestore - for instance, you can't return all documents NOT in a sub-collection (inequality-queries).

Ex: Return all users who I have NOT sent a message (not possible in Firestore)

To the best of my knowledge, the only way to accomplish this is to filter locally.

**My question is, am I correct that Google's Cloud Functions allows me to write Node.js queries that can perform inequality queries on data stored in Firestore and deploy on Google's cloud environment?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no language or runtime anywhere that supports [inequality queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals) with Firestore.  It's a fundamental limitation of the database, due to the way its massively scalable indexes work.  The best you can do is what's described in the linked issue.